# Can we update the "deleted answer" FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, sffaq

For answers to moved questions, the answer is deleted on ServerFault and you see:

```
Why was your post deleted? See the faq.
```

The FAQ does not cover this scenario, instead berating you for providing a poopy answer. Chances are rare that someone would see this for long, since the question itself is forwarded, but it's still something to note.

Comment: The correct answer is of course not to answer poopy questions ;)

Comment: @MarkHenderson Does the poop rub off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually IS there, in the sections no one, even FAQ mavens, reads:

https://serverfault.com/faq#deletion

Comment: But, but, the [Analyitcal](http://serverfault.com/badges/158/analytical) badge!

Comment: @jscott We all know this: *You can bring a user to the documentation, but you can't make them read it*.

Comment: Ehh, it's in there, but it's ambiguous at best :-P